# Why should there be a comma in this sentence before "because"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> It was supported by stating that a reliable fabric supplier has been found and that a major competitor is no longer making alpaca overcoats, **because** of which demand will be high.

Why is there a comma in this sentence?

Comment: Imagine reading the sentence out loud without making a pause!

Comment: Commaed and commaless examples seem equally popular in [Ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/because+of+which+the)'s corpus. Like Kate, I'd include it in this lengthy example: give the narrator a break.

Comment: If you didn't write the example sentence, then you should [cite the source](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). (If you did write it, then please say so.)

Comment: Because it's a non-restrictive relative clause, and these always need comma intonations. Say it out loud both ways and you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

"Because of which demand will be high" is a relative clause whose antecedent is most likely the phrase "a major competitor is no longer making alpaca overcoats." Relative clauses whose antecedents are themselves entire clauses characteristically use the relative pronoun "which" and are surrounded by commas.

"Because" here is not introducing a subordinate clause on its own; instead, it's part of the prepositional phrase "because of which," which contains a pied-piped relative pronoun.

Answer (score -2):

Generally speaking, a comma before "because" tends to be dealer's choice, more an issue of style than grammar and the choice to put one becoming more likely when it eliminates possible ambiguity.

At first, I considered that it's not what it appears, not simply a subordinate clause introduced by "because" but a nonrestrictive relative clause with an inverted structure that doesn't put "which" first, which would nonetheless require a comma, but it isn't. You can tell it isn't because you can readily substitute "that" for "which" and have it mean the exact same thing. Since "that" only introduces restrictive relative clauses and does not require a comma before the clause and since an alternate meaning of "which" is "that," even if the relative pronoun were the operative word and made that a relative clause, it still wouldn't *require* a comma, making any statement of "should" not on solid ground, but I ultimately decided that's not what it is. Just know that it wouldn't have mattered even if I had decided that's what it is or if that were what it is.

So why is it there? Because the writer chose to put it there, maybe feeling the sentence reads easier with it there than without it.

But "should" it be there? It "should" if the writer is obliged to follow a style guide that requires it. Otherwise, it's a matter of opinion since it's a matter of style, not grammar, making "should" an awfully strong word, probably too strong a word.

I will say that I like it there. I do think it reads easier with it than without it.

Comment: Replacing the "which" with "that" gives you a comma splice.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You're reading it wrong. You're reading it like it's a relative clause, like "that" has the meaning it has when we pronounce it like it rhymes with "mat," not like it has the meaning it has when we pronounce it like it rhymes with "met," which is how it'd be used here to mean what the "which" clearly means in that sentence, which is an idiomatic usage similar to when someone says, "Because of that it's cold outside, you should wear a coat," or says it's inversion, "You should wear a coat because of that it's cold outside."

Comment: The way that you're reading it, along with whomever else gave me that downvote, is reversing cause and effect, reversing what is being conveyed as the cause and the effect. It's an easy mistake to make, especially when one doesn't understand the subject matter or when focus on analyzing it mechanically for grammar has distracted one from internalizing its meaning, sort of like failing to see the forest for the trees.

Comment: In what dialect is "You should wear a coat because of that it's cold outside" grammatically correct? Certainly not in American English.

Comment: By the way, I would not disagree that using "which" idiomatically that way in this context feels clumsy, like something a kid would say casually and not what an adult would say formally. I suppose that may also be a contributing factor, because that one might not expect the usage in the given context. See what I did there? But that is neither here nor there since the OP isn't asking about that but about the comma usage.

Comment: It feels clumsy because it's wrong.

Comment: In American English. Look up the definition of "idiom." Then scan down through the definitions of "that" and/or "which" to find this particular idiomatic usage.

Comment: This is going over your head.

Comment: I have not been able to find any reference confirming your claims. In my own answer I've provided the straightforward and correct way of interpreting the sentence.

Comment: Regardless, even if you could use "because of that" in your proposed way, it wouldn't follow that "because of which" here isn't introducing a relative clause; it would only follow that you could replace that relative clause with an unrelated nonstandard construction.

Comment: An idiom is when the words or phrasing expresses a meaning that cannnot be readily derived from simply looking at the sum of what those words mean individually and ordering them, like someone saying, "He didn't learn me it," to mean, "He didn't teach it to me," for example. You may not like it, and it may not make sense when you take it literally, that is an idiom and an established idiomatic meaning, "irregardless." The usage of "irregardless" there to mean "regardless" or "regardlessly" is another example of an established idiom and its usage.

Comment: I've explained myself. That's all I'm required to do, not even required, actually, not by EL&U, anyway. People can read what you've said, what I've said, and choose. So more comment on this from you in this regard on my posted answer is trolling, chat that's no longer expressing anything new and so is merely argumentative and harassing in its perpetuation, especially when pushing your own answer, one I find to be incorrect, with reason, but haven't set about trolling by posting comment after comment on it to try and discredit it, letting my own answer and rationale stand for itself instead.